# segmentation fault when freeing the buffer after sendto()

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when freeing the buffer `'pkt'` after the function `sendto()`

```
u_char* create_pkt(u_char* pkt)
{
  ....
  pkt = (u_char *)malloc(40);
  ...
  return pkt
}


int main()
{
 ....
 u_char* pkt;
 create_pkt(pkt);
 if (sendto(sd, pkt, 40, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
 free(pkt);
 }
```

the debugging information shows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003897482864 in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7fffffffe010) at malloc.c:2986
```

what is wrong with this? thanks!

```
2986      ar_ptr = arena_for_chunk(p);
2986      ar_ptr = arena_for_chunk(p);
```

Comment: Why is `create_pkt()` even taking an argument?

Answer (score 2):

The `create_pkt` function returns the newly allocated value, so you'll need to use that in the calling function.

**`pkt =`**`create_pkt(pkt);`

Otherwise the program will just ignore the pointer to the allocated memory and use the original (unassigned) value of `pkt`.

Edit: if you want to use the argument as something to assign the value to, you can write something like this

```
void create_pkt(u_char** pkt)
{
  ....
  *pkt = (u_char *)malloc(40);
  ...
}
```

and call it with

```
create_pkt(&pkt);
```

but I can't really recomment that.

Comment: ah, yes, so this means my function should be u_char* create_pkt() but not u_char* create_pkt(u_char *)? the argument is useless?

Comment: In the current version, yes. Unless you use a "pointer-to-pointer" approach that lets you assign a value to the argument. And in that case, you won't need a return value. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`u_char* create_pkt(u_char* pkt)`  copies your pointer and then allocates it inside, but only allocates the *copy*.  When the function returns your original pointer is still as it was, unallocated.

Now you can either return a pointer from this function or pass in a double pointer `u_char** pkt` and assign the address of `pkt` to it.

`pkt = create_ptk(pkt);` now you'll have allocated pkt.

for double pointer version this is how you'd call it:

`create_pkt(&pkt);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate the memory and loosing the allocated reference. So the garbage is sent and then attempt to release kills it.

```
u_char* create_pkt()
{
   u_char* pkt;
   ....
   pkt = (u_char *)malloc(40);
  ...
   return pkt;
}


int main()
{
   ....
   u_char* pkt;
   pkt = create_pkt();
   if (sendto(sd, pkt, 40, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
   free(pkt);
}
```